# Is there a way to create a MySQL table with a rails migration where the table doesn't have UPDATE permissions?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm looking to create a read-only table, and MYSQL permissions, I think, are the best way to do that.

Is this possible via a migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a migration file as follows,

```
rails g migration add_permissions_to_table_name    
invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20120620191050_add_permissions_to_table_name.rb
```

Edit the file as follows,

think@thinkComputer:~/Agile/ajax1$ vi db/migrate20120620191050_add_permissions_to_table_name.rb

```
class AddPermissionsToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    execute "GRANT SELECT ON database1.table_name TO 'someuser'@'somehost'"

  end

  def down

    execute "REVOKE SELECT ON database1.table_name TO 'someuser'@'somehost'"

  end

end
```

Run the rake task as follows,

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

In future if you want to revoke that permission, then do,

```
$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20120620191050
```

You would want to be the a mysql user who has grant permissions on "database1.table_name", other wise you will get the following error,

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON database1.table_name TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
ERROR 1142 (42000): GRANT command denied to user 'current_mysql_user'@'localhost' for table 'table_name'
```

**The details about the mysql user and database is located in "config/database.yml"**

Please let me know if this works!

Comment: For the revoke the syntax is FROM 'someuser'@'somehost' not TO, at least in mysql

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit your models you can:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :your_field_name
end
```

It's not a migration but is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Oh! I hadn't considered that Sean. Thats a good and simple one! Anyway, my answer would change it in the database itself and yours wont, I guess. Great answer!

Comment: wouldn't it still be possible to modify the database though? like, attr_readonly is only from within rails. Or does this actually set some permission on the SQL table?